# Does MessageBoxW call GetMessageW with a NULL hWnd?

Tags: winapi

I have some `Debug.Assert` statements in the shutdown code of my winforms application. When I'm using the `ConsoleTraceListener`, `Debug.Assert` behaves as you'd expect. When I use the `DefaultTraceListener`, the pop-up assert window locks up and the buttons are unresponsive and the stacktrace shows a nested exception in the message processing of my **main** window.

It would appear that `Debug.Assert` is, effectively, resuming the message-pump of my **main** window.

I dug into the .NET Framework reference source, to figure out how that could happen (for example, perhaps `Debug.Assert` is causing a loop of `Application.DoEvents()`) and found that internally `DefaultTraceListener` was calling `MessageBoxW`.

If `MessageBoxW` was calling `GetMessageW` with its own `hWnd`, it wouldn't be dispatching the messages for my main window, right? So am I correct to assume that, for some reason, `MessageBoxW` is calling `GetMessageW` with a NULL `hWnd`?

Comment: Have you seen the documentation for the `MB_TASKMODAL` flag? "Use this flag when the calling application or library does not have a window handle available but still needs to prevent input to other windows in the calling thread without suspending other threads."

Comment: @Dai `DefaultTraceListener` is passing `MB_TOPMOST` and `MB_SERVICE_NOTIFICATION` and some others, but **not** `MB_TASKMODAL`. Weird; it sounds like it **should** have that flag; that sounds like it would fix my problem exactly.

Comment: This question is about the behavior of `MessageBoxW`, which has nothing to do with `C#` or `WinForms`

Comment: In fact it is exceedingly unusual for GetMessage to be called with anything other than NULL as the hwnd arg.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In answer to your question, yes MessageBoxW causes a secondary message loop to run (I doubt MessageBoxW implements that loop itself, instead relying on DialogBox to do that work).

And if it did not use a null HWND for the filter then windows other than the dialog would not even get painted while the message box is displayed.

Comment: [The dangers of filtering window messages](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050209-00/?p=36493)